# Can a custom view get something like "onClose" or "onDestroy" event?

Tags: android, android-custom-view

I have created a custom compound view by extending `FrameLayout`. That view can be on a dialogue box (among others). But what if I want to do some clean-up work when the view disappears from the screen, such as the user's closing the dialogue box? Can I get some kind of `onDestroy` event? Or should I make the owner (such as the dialogue box or the fragment) call the view's clean-up method on its (owner's) `onDestroy` or dismissed event?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

try to use

```
@Override
protected void onDetachedFromWindow() {
    super.onDetachedFromWindow();
}
```